# Calling bash script recursively with different parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

I'm trying to write a bash script that counts all the files in the given directory & sub-directories, so I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=0
if ["$#" == "0"]
    directory="$(echo pwd)"
  then
    directory=$1
fi

echo $directory;
for x in `ls -l $directory | grep "^-" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9`;
do
var=$((var+1))
done

for x in `ls -l $directory | grep "^d" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9`;
do
output = "$($0 $x)"
done

var=$((var+output))
echo $var
```

But I get something like this:

```
./lala2
./lala2: line 4: [0: command not found

test
./lala2: line 4: [1: command not found
./lala2: line 4: [1: command not found
```

Why is that? Are the variables global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
if ["$#" == "0"]
```

with:

```
if [ "$#" = "0" ]
```

Some comments:

1. In shell, spaces are important.  If you want the shell to recognize the test command, `[`, there must be spaces around the `[`.

   Spaces are not important for shell keywords but [`[`, unlike `[[`, is a command, not a keyword.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183749/53604)
2. The meaning of the error message `[0: command not found` is that `"$#"` evaluated to 0 so that the string `["$#"` became `[0` and bash could find no command by the name of `[0`.
3. It is possible to use `==` for string equality in bash.  It is, however, no portable.  In POSIX, the correct equality operator in `[...]` is `=`.  This becomes very important if you run your script, either intentionally [or unintentionally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33616280/3030305), under a POSIX shell like `dash`.

#### Other issues

1. Once again, spaces matter.  When the shell sees this command:

   ```
   output = "$($0 $x)"
   ```

   it will try to execute a command called `output` and provide it with two arguments, the first being `=` and the second being the result of `"$($0 $x)"`.  Consequently, as Gordon Davisson points out, that line
   should be replaced with:

   ```
   output="$($0 $x)"
   ```

   Because there are no spaces around the `=`, the shell will treat this as a variable assignment.
2. The script attempts to parse the output of `ls` and [this is unreliable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  In this case, it will lead to errors if any of the subdirectory names contain whitespace.
3. As rici points out, the command `directory="$(echo pwd)"` likely does not do what you expect.  Observe:

   ```
   $ directory="$(echo pwd)"
   $ echo "$directory"
   pwd
   ```

   This command assigns the string `pwd` to the variable `directory`.  Probably, you want the current working directory, like this:

   ```
   directory=$(pwd)
   ```

   But, it is simpler than that.  In Unix, the current working directory is always `.`:

   ```
   directory=.
   ```
4. There are other reasons that this if-then statement does not do what one might hope:

   ```
   if ["$#" == "0"]
       directory="$(echo pwd)"
     then
       directory=$1
   fi
   ```

   You likely want to move the `then` statement and add an `else` statement:

   ```
   if [ "$#" = "0" ]
   then
       directory=.
   else
       directory="$1"
   fi
   ```

#### Alternative script

If the goal is to count the number of regular files in a directory and all its subdirectories, then try:

```
echo "$(find "$directory" -type f -printf "1\n" | wc -l)"
```

This approach is safe to use even if the file or directory names contain whitespace or other difficult characters.

Comment: Also, while spaces are required in a test (or `[`) command, they're forbidden in assignments. So `output = "$($0 $x)"` must be changed to `output="$($0 $x)"`. (And I'd also say that spaces are significant for keywords as well as commands: `[["$#"` won't work any better than `["$#"`.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes.  Excellent point.  I added discussion of assignments to the answer.

Comment: `directory="$(echo pwd)"` is also almost certainly wrong. (Unless `directory=pwd` was intended, in which case it is merely redundant.)

Comment: @rici Good observation.  I added a discussion of `echo pwd` to the answer also.

Comment: Curiously, although your point 4 is 100% correct, the incorrect code will have the intended effect. `directory=$(echo pwd)` *always* succeeds, so the `then` clause will always be executed; if `$1` is not assigned, then that will assign `directory=` and later on `ls -l $directory` will expand to `ls -l ` instead of `ls -l ''`, which is what you would get if the variable expansion had been correctly quoted. I think this is what is called a "comedy of errors".